# How to programmatically generate and store HMacSHA256 key in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore

I would like to generate and store a HMacSHA256 key for testing purposes in the Java keystore.

I would normally do this via the keytool:

```
keytool -genseckey -keystore keystore.jceks -storetype jceks -storepass secret -keyalg HMacSHA256 -keysize 2048 -alias HS256 -keypass secret
```

So far I found that I can generate the key using:

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("secret".getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
```

That key is unfortunately not an instance of `PrivateKey` and thus storing the key fails:

```
    KeyStore ks = ...
    ks.setEntry("HS256", new SecretKeyEntry(key), new PasswordProtection("secret".toCharArray()));
```

Exception:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:258)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineSetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:550)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:179)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineSetEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.setEntry(KeyStore.java:1557)
    at com.gentics.mesh.SecretKeyTest.testSHA(SecretKeyTest.java:31)
```

I believe that `SecretKey` represents a symmetric key. And `PrivateKey` is part of a `PublicKey` and Private-Key Pair. Is there a way to store a single symmetric key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. But until Java 9 comes out, PKCS#12 key stores will be limited in functionality. JCEKS key stores as you are using in the command line `keytool` do however support symmetric (HMAC) keys:

```
public class HMACKeyStore {
    public static void gen( String thePath, String thePassword ) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks");
        keystore.load(null, null);

        // This call throws an exception
        keystore.setKeyEntry("theKey", key, thePassword.toCharArray(), null);
        keystore.store( new FileOutputStream(thePath), thePassword.toCharArray() );

        SecretKey keyRetrieved = (SecretKey) keystore.getKey("theKey", thePassword.toCharArray());
        System.out.println(keyRetrieved.getAlgorithm());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        gen("hmac_store.jceks", "password");
    }
}
```

should work fine on Java 8.